# CRUD: DELETE is called before user calls

Tags: node.js, angular, web-services, crud

Once I open localhost:4200 app, there is already an old delete request. My new delete request does not work either when pressing the delete button (404 (Not Found)), though it *does* delete the item after manually entering the URL into the search bar.

[Pre-loaded delete request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZUiK.png)

[image]

[404 (Not Found) Error using button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWef9.png)

[image]

```
//rug-list.component.ts
...
    deleteRug(rug: Rug): void {
        if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete rug: ${rug.name}?`)) {
            this.rugService.deleteRug(rug.id).subscribe( // "id" is not the mongo-assigned variable "_id", but rather a custom var of the rug object
                res => { console.log('Deleted'); }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

```
//rug.service.ts
...
deleteRug(id: number): Observable<{}> { 
        return this.http.delete<Rug>(`${this.uri}/${id}/delete`);
    }
```

```
//rug.route.js
...
rugRoutes.route('/:id/delete', { useFindAndModify: false }).get(function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Rug.findOneAndDelete({ "id": id }, function (err) {
        if (err) { return res.json(err); }
        else { res.json('Successfully deleted'); }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post as much of your code related to your issue. It will be hard for anyone to advise otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see answer: [GET http://localhost:4000/rugs 500 (Internal Server Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658124/get-http-localhost4000-rugs-500-internal-server-error)

Change this.http.delete to this.http.get, matching .get() in rug.route.js

```
//rug.service.ts
...
deleteRug(id: number): Observable<{}> { 
        return this.http.get<Rug>(`${this.uri}/${id}/delete`);
    }
```